# Matlab extract from a cell of strings by regexp

Tags: matlab

I have a cell of a couple of thousand strings that contain one or more underscores as shown below:

```
cel={'ABC_D234_567','ABD_X157_224','PT_D204_157','PT_O268_578','DTA_P2345','CBDRT_X345_D325};
```

I need to extract all the letters before the first underscore and one letter after; for example, 'ABC_D', 'PT_O', or 'CBDRT_X'.

I figured out a way to do so by using strfind, but it's several lines of code; finding indices for all underscores, using only the indices for the first underscores, then extracting strings from 1 to (index+1).

I'm pretty sure one can do this in one or fewer lines; something like:

```
cel_new = regexe(cel,'something something','once','match');
```

What would this 'something something' be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cellfun` to apply this operations to each element of a cell. like

```
cel={'ABC_D234_567','ABD_X157_224','PT_D204_157','PT_O268_578','DTA_P2345','CBDRT_X345_D325'};

cel_new=cellfun(@(x) regexprep(x,'^([A-Z]+_[A-Z]).*','$1','once'), cel,'uni',false)
```

`regexprep` helps you find and extract the pattern, and `cellfun` applies this to each string in the cell.